# .Net Web API SerializationException

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I am writing a simple API using .Net's Web API.  I have defined the following Model:

```
public class VehicleUpdate
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "DealerID Required")]
    public int DealerID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "VIN Required")]
    [StringLength(17, ErrorMessage = "VIN Must be 17 characters", MinimumLength = 17)]
    public string VIN { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8000, ErrorMessage = "Comments must be less than 8,000 characters")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public double Retail { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to test it by doing an HTTP Post with the following XML

```
<VehicleUpdate>
    <DealerID>30</DealerID>
    <VIN>1FMRU17L0WLA62356</VIN>
    <Comments>This is a test.</Comments>
    <Retail>1000</Retail>
</VehicleUpdate>
```

When I do this, I get the following SerializationException:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1
>   position 16. Expecting element 'VehicleUpdate' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API.Models'.. Encountered
>   'Element'  with name 'VehicleUpdate', namespace ''.     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader
>   reader)    at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_2()

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I thought this would be a valid XML message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

AS the error says, `DataContractSerializer` expects the XML to provide a proper namespace, and your XML doesn't have it.
You can either pass the namespace:

```
<VehicleUpdate xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API.Models">
 // properties
</VehicleUpdate>
```

Or switch to `XmlSerializer` in your Web API configuration:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Then you can pass the exact XML you are passing now.

You might run into another issue, when using `[Required]` on non nullable type i.e. `int`. This is a known problem since `int` will be always 0 instead of null if not passsed. In that case you might have to change your model to have excplicit `DataContract` definition:

```
  [DataContract]
    public class VehicleUpdate
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "DealerID Required")]
        public int DealerID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "VIN Required")]
        [StringLength(17, ErrorMessage = "VIN Must be 17 characters", MinimumLength = 17)]
        public string VIN { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [StringLength(8000, ErrorMessage = "Comments must be less than 8,000 characters")]
        public string Comments { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public double Retail { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a reference and using statement to System.Runtime.Serialization

Comment: Then I updated my model with the DataContract and DataMember declarations and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
//....
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {  config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
        Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
}
```